# Synchronization of multiple tasks on single thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift3

How can I prevent a block of code to be repeatedly accessed from the same thread?

Suppose, I have the next code:

```
func sendAnalytics() {
    // some synchronous work

    asyncTask() { _ in
        completion()
    }
}
```

I want to prevent **any** thread from accessing "// some synchronous work", before completion was called.

```
objc_sync_enter(self)
objc_sync_exit(self)
```

seem to only prevent accessing this code from multiple threads and don't save me from accessing this code from the single thread. Is there a way to do this correctly, without using custom solutions?

My repeatedly accessing, I mean calling this sendAnalytics from one thread multiple times. Suppose, I have a for, like this:

```
for i in 0...10 {
    sendAnalytics()
}
```

Every next call won't be waiting for completion inside sendAnalytics get called (obvious). Is there a way to make the next calls wait, before completion fires? Or the whole way of thinking is wrong and I have to solve this problem higher, at the for body?

Comment: It depends whether you want to block the second caller until the first has finished or simply skip the second call

Comment: block the second caller

Comment: Then use a dispatch_semaphore with an initial count of 0. Beware of blocking the main queue however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `DispatchSemaphore` to ensure that one call completes before the next can start

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:1)

func sendAnalytics() {
    self.semaphore.wait()
    // some synchronous work

    asyncTask() { _ in
        completion()
        self.semaphore.signal()
    }
}
```

The second call to `sendAnalytics` will block until the first asyncTask is complete.  You should be careful not to block the main queue as that will cause your app to become non-responsive.  It is probably safer to dispatch the `sendAnalytics` call onto its own serial dispatch queue to eliminate this risk:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:1)
let analyticsQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"analyticsQueue")

func sendAnalytics() {
    analyticsQueue.async {
        self.semaphore.wait()
        // some synchronous work

        asyncTask() { _ in
            completion()
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't call at all, for me. but it works for

let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value:1)